# Grab first 4 characters of two words RegEx

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

I would like to grab the first 4 characters of two words using RegEx. I have some RegEx experinece however a search did not yeild any results.

So if I have `Awesome Sauce` I would like the end result to be `AwesSauc`

Comment: Do you need to use Regex? This could be done in 1-line of Linq: `String.Join( " ", input.Split( null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).Select( w => w.Substring( 0, Math.Min( 4, w.Length ) )`.

Comment: @Dai Just because OP has *some RegEx experinece*

Comment: I'm using Nintex to complete the operation so I'm bound by RegEx

Comment: can there be also more or less than 2 words? If more - should the RegEx take the first 4 characters of every word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Replace Text* action with the following parameters:

**Pattern**: `\W*\b(\p{L}{1,4})\w*\W*` 
**Replacement text**: `$1`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CW*%5Cb%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B1%2C4%7D%29%5Cw*%5CW*&i=Awesome%20Sauce&r=%241).

Pattern details:

- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars (trim from the left)
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(\p{L}{1,4})` - Group 1 (later referred to via `$1` backreference) matching any 1 to 4 letters (incl. Unicode ones)
- `\w*` - any 0+ word chars (to match the rest of the word)
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars (trim from the right)

Answer (score 1):

I think this RegEx should do the job

```
        string pattern = @"\b\w{4}";
        var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        while (match.Captures.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var capture in match.Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(capture);
            }
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }

        // outputs:
        // quic
        // brow
        // jump
        // over
        // lazy
```

Alternatively you could use patterns like:

```
        \b\w{1,4} => The, quic, brow, fox, jump, over, the, lazy, dog
        \b[\w|\d]{1,4} => would also match digits
```

**Update:** 
added a full example for C# and modified the pattern slightly. Also added some alternative patterns.

Comment: It matches `Awes` and `Sauc` as expected. I was just thinking @Dai's comment about word length < 4 on my answer applies even here.

Comment: If it should capture also < 4 characters AND numeric characters than @G Ravinders answer would be a suitable solution.

Comment: `\w` already matches digits, in .NET regex, `\w` = `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`.

Answer (score 0):

one approach with `Linq`

```
var res = new string(input.Split().SelectMany((x => x.Where((y, i) => i < 4))).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex would in fact be more complex and totally unnecessary for this case. Just do it as either of the below.

```
var sentence = "Awesome        Sau";

// With LINQ
var linqWay = string.Join("", sentence.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), options:StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Substring(0, Math.Min(4,x.Length))).ToArray());

// Without LINQ
var oldWay = new StringBuilder();
string[] words = sentence.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), options:StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var word in words) {
    oldWay.Append(word.Substring(0, Math.Min(4, word.Length)));
}
```

**Edit**:

Updated code based on @Dai's comment. `Math.Min` check borrowed as is from his suggestion.

Comment: This code will crash if any word in the input string is shorter than 4 characters. It also doesn't handle multiple contiguous whitespace characters - or handle non-space whitespace.

Comment: @Dai - Great catch. Thanks a lot. See edit. Seems OP is restricted to Regex.

Comment: I suggest using `.Split( null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )` as that splits on all whitespace characters, not just spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}
```