# Adjustment to this code to stop after finding two words

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

In my haste to get this working I failed to ask how to stop after the second word in my original post. [Grab first 4 characters of two words RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337674/grab-first-4-characters-of-two-words-regex/43338498#43338498)

If I have `Awesome Sauce Today` I would like to have `AwesSauc`

The code in my first post will capture the first 4 characters of any word and combine them. so `Awesome Sauce Today` will become `AwesSaucToda`. I want it to stop capturing after the second word. So in my example `Today` would be ignored but it will still capture 4 characters of the first two words it encounters to create the new wor `AwesSauc`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nintex, but it looks like a text editor of some sort.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  If you just want to build your output string, a find and replace should work.  Or, are you trying to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may still use the *Replace Text* action and use

**Pattern**: `(?s)^\P{L}*(\p{L}{1,4})\p{L}*\P{L}+(\p{L}{1,4}).*`
**Replacement text**: `$1$2`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%5E%5CP%7BL%7D*%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B1%2C4%7D%29%5Cp%7BL%7D*%5CP%7BL%7D%2B%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B1%2C4%7D%29.*&i=Awesome%20Sauce%20Today%0D%0Aand%20more%20words%20here&r=%241%242).

The difference between this solution and the previous one  is that the pattern is anchored at the start with `^`, instead of a `\W` (that matches any non-word char) I am using a `\P{L}` that matches any non-letter char (adjust as you see fit), and to match the first and second word beginning, I am using 2 capturing groups now (`(\p{L}{1,4})...(\p{L}{1,4})`), hence two backreferences in the replacement pattern. The `(?s)` modifier makes the `.` pattern to match any char, including a newline. The `.*` at the end is necessary to remove the rest of the string after the necessary text is captured into the  2 capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks I see it now. I really appreciate it